# Xamarin Timer crashes

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I've done this in code:

```
public partial class Timer : ContentView , INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int seconds = 30;
        
        private System.Timers.Timer timer;
        public Timer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OneSecondPassed);
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }
        private void OneSecondPassed(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            seconds--;
            Time = seconds.ToString();
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public string Time
        {
            get => seconds.ToString();
            set
            {
                Time = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this ,  new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Time"));
                }
                
            }   
        }
    }
```

and then bound my label's text to it in XAML:

```
 <Label  BindingContext ="{x:Reference this}"
              Text="{Binding Time}"/>
```

When I start the app, it crashes...I don't really understand how PropertyChanged works, just that INotifyPropertyChanged implements it.Also, when I declare PropertyChanged, it tells me that BindableObject.PropertyChanged already exists, use new in order to hide it.If you could explain how the interface and its event works, I'd be really thankful.

Comment: What ist the Exception/Error message?

Comment: You may need to change value of `Text` property using [`Dispatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.application.dispatcher?view=xamarin-forms), otherwise bindings run on wrong thread, ThreadPool perhaps? [Timer documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0). May be mitigated by setting Timer's [SynchronizingObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject?view=net-6.0) to say `this`?

Answer (score 2):

your setter is creating an infinite loop.

```
set
{
   // this will call the setter again, infinitely
   Time = value;
   ...
}
```

you already have a private variable for `seconds`, you should use it here

```
public int Time
    {
        get => seconds;
        set
        {
            seconds = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this ,  new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Time"));
            }
            
        }   
    }

private void OneSecondPassed(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   Time--;
}
```

Comment: I want the Time property to be of type string so I can bind my label's text to it...So I can't really do Time--;

Comment: Sure you can.  You can bind an int to a label - .NET will automatically convert it for you.

Comment: The label still stays the same...any idea?

Comment: I am thinking of just saying label.text = seconds--.ToString() every second instead of using binding..

Comment: binding should work as long as the update is happening on the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

> when I declare PropertyChanged, it tells me that BindableObject.PropertyChanged already exists

I see that `Timer` inherits from `ContentView`.

`ContentView` is a `BindableObject`, so it already implements everything used in binding, such as PropertyChanged. Delete your declaration of `PropertyChanged`.

---

OPTIONAL: You could also remove `, INotifyPropertyChanged` - `ContentView` does that for you. However it is harmless to leave it there.

Comment: Oh , that's good to know!It was pretty confusing